# How can I programmatically modify an aspx file content before the handler handle it?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, httpmodule

The reason I need to modify the content of an aspx (not physically, but change the content in the memory) is because there are certain custom tags I made needs to be parsed to the correct data before the entire aspx is handled by the HttpHandler.

Is there a way for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Response Filters (HttpFilter) and modify content on the fly, basically after response is formed, before EndRequest your filter is called (it's a stream descendant) and you can modify it as you wish. In the HttpModule, Init method you got to install HttpFilter (Response.Filter) and it will be called for that request.

Here is a good article :

http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters

UPDATE: 
Maybe this is a case of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and you can solve your problem with simple server control that will render these custom tags properly.

Comment: thanks - but I need to parse the document before it is handled by aspx handler - any sugestions?

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by document ? There is nothing to parse before Request is handled.

Comment: Probably he wants to see the content of an ASPX file as one string, modify it and then let it flow through the ASP.NET pipeline for being interpreted as an actual ASPX page.

Comment: Well if that is the case, it's IMO wrong approach to the problem, if nothing else regarding to performance, and it's much more complicated then dealing with that custom tag in simple server control.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Render event

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)


    Dim sw As New System.IO.StringWriter
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    MyBase.Render(hw)
    Dim html As String = sw.ToString()

    ' html = html.Replace() etc to change your html code in here

    writer.Write(html)
End Sub
```

EDIT i see you want to  inject mark up dynamically before asp.net handles the aspx, maybe the [FileLevelPageControlBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.filelevelpagecontrolbuilder.aspx) Class is of use

Comment: thanks - but I need to parse the document before it is handled by aspx handler - so basically it's much earlier before the page events.